when does $h$ exist?
Let $\zeta(s)$ denote the Reimann zeta function in the critical strip. It is easy to see that $$ \zeta(s) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \Re(\zeta(s))+\Im(\zeta(s)) = 0 ~~~~ \text{and} ~~~~~~ \Re(\zeta(s)) \Im(\zeta(s))=0$$.
Define $f: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by the rules $$f(s) =\Re(\zeta(s))+\Im(\zeta(s)),~~~~~~~~~ g(s) =  \Re(\zeta(s))\Im(\zeta(s)).$$
Is there a function $h$ so that $h(g(s)) = f(s)$?
I tried to start with partial sums of zeta function for finite value then take the product and after take the limit as so
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}{\biggl( \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\Re(s)}} \cos(\Im(s) \ln(n))\biggr)\biggl( \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\Re(s)}} \sin(\Im(s) \ln(n))\biggr)} = \Re(\eta(s))\Im(\eta(s))$$ with $\eta(s)$ the Dirichlet eta function.
maybe proceed by expanding this finite product and taking limit after but it does not seem to be going in a useful direction. I want to try and find for which values of $s$ does $h$ exist. If it does always exist try to find it.

There is no such function $h$, not just for the Riemann zeta function in the critical strip but for any non-constant holomorphic function $v:D\to\mathbb{C}$ defined on an open disk $D\subset\mathbb{C}$. Indeed, let $f=\Re(v)+\Im(v)$ and $g=\Re(v)\Im(v)$. Assume that a function $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ exists such that $h(g(s))=f(s)$ holds for all $s\in D$. Then $g(s)$ determines $f(s)$, hence it also determines $v(s)$ up to two choices. On the other hand, the range $\{v(s):s\in D\}$ is open, hence it contains whole arcs on certain hyperbolas $\{x+iy:(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2,\ xy=c\}$. Contradiction.

what about the function $h(s) = f(s)/g(s)$ when $g$ is non-zero. If we take $g(s)*h(s)$ we find $g(s)*h(s) = g(s)(f(s)/g(s)) = f(s)$.

@RoyBurson Yes, but $h(g(s))$ does not equal $f(s)$. It equals $f(g(s))/g(g(s))$.

i see, don't understand proof all the way otherwise i would put a thumbs up. ill keep reading lol it seems then that they are independent of one another in this sense. This means we cannot determine the real part from imaginary part we need more info to do so. This where the quantum stuff may come in handy lol

can we conclude that if $\Re(\zeta(s)) =\epsilon$ we cannot determine the imaginary part as function of $\epsilon$. So this means the real part and imaginary part are independent of one another. They do not depend on each other.  So there is no way to determine what the other one is relative to each other. Its like saying the problem is unsolvable

if real part is ever zero and we cannot ever say anything conclusively about imaginary part simultaneously this means we cannot decide a conclusion. It may be zero it may not be, but we cannot use this to determine it. We either need more information. A third equation, something that happens only when its zero. It almost appears impossible to determine zeroes from this discussion. If this relationship doesn't exist I suspect we will never find answer.

@RoyBurson If $v:D\to\mathbb{C}$ is any holomorphic function on an open disk $D\subset\mathbb{C}$, then the real-valued functions $\Re(v)$ and $\Im(v)$ determine each other up to a constant shift. This is a classical fact (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_conjugate). What you asked is something else. At any rate, my proof shows after a bit of tweaking that if $v$ is not constant, then there is a whole curve in $D$ along which $\Re(v)\Im(v)$ is constant but $\Re(v)+\Im(v)$ is injective. I stop here as these comments are not meant for lengthy discussions (MO is not a chat site).

okay sure thanks appreciate it
